# Smooth decelerate, interpolation?

Tags: interpolation

I have two points A and B.  I want to perform a smooth deceleration from A stopping at B over time t.  The only thing I managed to do so far was a lerp, which isn't right of course because it's unnatural.  I also tried multiplying the velocity by some factor (0.9 or similar), but then I don't know how to choose the factor such that the end point B is reached (or as near to it as some epsilon value seems reasonable).

Does anyone have something relatively simple that I could use?  I can read C++ and C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the ratio `x` in [0,1] of the current animation time and the animation duration `t`. Then use something like `sqrtf(x)` to decelerate. Compute the current position `C = A + x * (B - A)`. You can make it decelerate more rapidly by using e.g. `powf(x, f)` with `f = 1.0f / 3` or smaller.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you mean multiply subtract (decelerate) by sqrtf(t) * velocity?

Comment: First of all, I fixed the variable naming in my response because it was a little misleading that I used `t` differently than you did in your question.

Comment: The only thing you need is your points A and B and the time it takes to get from A to B. In regular intervals, you compute `x` as described in my response and compute your current position C between A and B.

Comment: OK I finished my implementation (it's a virtual surface that pans and "bounces", kind-of like a mobile phone or slate surface) and it works great.  Prefer the powf function to sqrt however.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the "Arrive" behavior from [Millington's book](http://ai4g.com/) *Artificial Intelligence for Games*.

It's important to say that you need to constantly update positionB in order for it to work correctly.

```
float targetRadius = 0.1f;
float timeToTarget = 0.1f;
float maxSpeed = 10.0f;

Vector3 positionA;
Vector3 positionB;
Vector3 agentVelocity;

// calculation for slow radius given the initial
// distance between the two positions
Vector3 dist = positionB - positionA;
float slowRadius = dist.Length();

public Vector3 GetVelocity ()
{
    Vector3 velocity = new Vector3();
    Vector3 direction = positionB - positionA;
    float distance = direction.Lenght();
    float targetSpeed;
    if (distance < targetRadius)
        return velocity;
    if (distance > slowRadius)
        targetSpeed = maxSpeed;
    else
        targetSpeed = maxSpeed * distance / slowRadius;
    velocity = direction;
    velocity.Normalize();
    velocity *= targetSpeed;
    velocity -= agentVelocity;
    velocity /= timeToTarget;
    return velocity;
}
```